# IosSlider images loading vertically (or scattered) on initial page load

Tags: jquery, ios, css, slider

This should be a simple fix but I'm not experienced enough to figure out issue.  My website is using the IosSlider on several pages.   The IosSlider pages appear to load the images vertically (or scattered) prior to loading the images into the actual slider window.  How do I fix this to make the slider load smoother?  The issue happens on all browsers.

http://www.restipe.com/Residential/elegant-home.html

**CSS for IOSSlider:**

```
       .responsiveHeight {
            height: 0;
            padding: 0 0 40% 0; /* responsive slider height = 40% of the browser width */
            position: relative;
            overflow: visible;
        }

        .responsiveHeight > .inner {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }

        .iosSlider {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }

        .iosSlider .slider {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .iosSlider .slider img {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            padding-right:2px;
        }

        .responsiveHeight .prevButton {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 1%;
            width: 20px;
            height: 40px;
            background-image: url(../images/prev.png);      
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .responsiveHeight .nextButton {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right:1%;
            width: 20px;
            height: 40px;
            background-image: url(../images/next.png);          
            z-index: 2;
        }
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">      </script>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.iosslider.js"></script>


<!--IosSlider -->   
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {

            $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({ 
            desktopClickDrag: true,
            navNextSelector: $('.nextButton'),
            navPrevSelector: $('.prevButton')

             });

        });
    </script>
```

Thank you,
Jill

Comment: without a fiddle it's difficult to tweek your css to try to fix your problem. Looks to me like the container of your slider needs overflow:hidden (or one of their parents)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how the images are placed after the plugin is loaded. The way the slider works is to place each image at an absolute position, and applies it to each individual one. A floated element will only fill as wide as its parent container, so when the elements aren't yet placed absolutely, and the parent container is 1140px wide, an image of 593px will only fit once inside of it.

Now, this solution isn't 100% perfect, because the plugin resizes the images a little bit, but for the most part you could solve this by setting:

```
.iosSlider { overflow: hidden; }
.iosSlider .slider { width: 99999px; }
```

This will get your images to line up very close to how the slider will display them.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Setting {overflow: hidden} worked.  I did not need to set the width of the slider in pixels.  I knew it was a simple solution I just couldn't figure it out.